# exam: Create a \NewDocumentCommand for changing the question format on the fly

Tags: tcolorbox, exam, xparse

I need to create a command `\QuestionFormat` that accepts two optional arguments with a default value for the first one while testing the existence of the second one.

The following doesn't work, while the desired output is written under each line in the document. So, what went wrong here?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewTColorBox { MarksTCBox } { O{} }
{
    left~skip= 0pt,right~skip=0pt, left=2pt,right=2pt, capture=hbox,
halign=center, valign=center, boxrule=0pt, arc=0pt, top=2pt,
bottom=2pt, boxsep=0pt, colback=lg, nobeforeafter, box~align = base, baseline=4pt, #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand \QuestionFormat { O{Question} O{} }
{
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
    {\qformat{\textbf{%
                \underline{%
                    {%
                        \large #1 (\thequestion) 
                        \begin{MarksTCBox}
                            [\totalpoints\ Marks]
                        \end{MarksTCBox}%
                    }%
                }%
            }\hfill%
    }}
    {\qformat{\textbf{%
                \underline{%
                    {%
                        \large #1 (\thequestion) (#2)
                        \begin{MarksTCBox}
                            [\totalpoints\ Marks]
                        \end{MarksTCBox}%
                    }%
                }%
            }%\hfill%
    }}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}

        \QuestionFormat
        \question[15]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Question 1 [15 Marks]"

        \QuestionFormat[Part]
        \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Part 2 [10 Marks]"

        \QuestionFormat[Part][Subtitle]
        \question[5]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Part 3 [5 Marks] (Subtitle)"

        \QuestionFormat[][Subtitle]
        \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Question 4 [10 Marks] (Subtitle)"

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\ExplSyntaxOn` spaces are ignored. This means `left skip` is the same as `leftskip`. Spaces are input with `~` in expl syntax so you should write `left~skip`. (Should be the same with `box align`)

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for the hint. I fixed it but the document still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not `\ExplSyntaxOn` everywhere.

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\NewTColorBox{MarksTCBox} { O{} }{
  left skip= 0pt,
  right skip=0pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  capture=hbox,
  halign=center,
  valign=center,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  top=2pt,
  bottom=2pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
%  colback=lg,
  nobeforeafter,
  box align = base,
  baseline=4pt,
  #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \QuestionFormat { O{Question} o }{%
  \qformat{
    \textbf{
      \underline{
        \large \tl_if_blank:nTF {#1} { Question } { #1 }~
        (\thequestion)\ \IfValueT{#2}{(#2)\ }
        \begin{MarksTCBox}
        \scan_stop: [\totalpoints\ Marks]
        \end{MarksTCBox}
      }
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}

        \QuestionFormat
        \question[15]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Question 1 [15 Marks]''

        \QuestionFormat[Part]
        \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Part 2 [10 Marks]''

        \QuestionFormat[Part][Subtitle]
        \question[5]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Part 3 [5 Marks] (Subtitle)''

        \QuestionFormat[][Subtitle]
        \question[10]\hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}
        The output should be ``Question 4 [10 Marks] (Subtitle)''

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Note `\scan_stop:` that stops LaTeX into thinking that `[` starts an optional argument. Also note how to avoid code duplication by using the `o` argument specifier and `\IfValueT`.

[image]

I commented out `colback=lg` because the color definition is missing.

By the way, is underlining needed at all?

Comment: "Also note how to avoid code duplication by using the `o` argument specifier"; will the code be fragile when using `O` for both optional arguments? For the underlining, I follow a template sent to me.

Comment: @Diaa With your code using `O` you have to specify the same code twice. There is no problem of robustness in either case.